# ForkJoin not able to fork observables from multiple declared Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

I have two function which makes two HTTP call and saved the data return from the request. Along with it, it also send the success response to the observer of the Subject returned from this function like this.

```js
import { Observable, of, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

export class subjectServices : : Observable<any>{
dataone : any;
constructor(private http :HttpClient){}

  observableOne() : Observable<any>{
    let subjectOne = new Subject<any>();
    let subjectOneObserver = subjectOne.asObservable();
    this.http.get('url').subcribe(data=>{
       this.dataone = data;
       subjectOne.next("Success"); 
       //subjectOne.complete("Success");
       // changing "next" to "complete" makes it works     
      })
    return subjectOneObserver;
  }


  observableTwo() : Observable<any>{
    let subjectTwo = new Subject<any>();
    let subjectTwoObserver = subjectTwo.asObservable();
    this.http.get('url').subcribe(data=>{
      this.dataTwo = data;
      subjectTwo.next("Success");
      //subjectTwo.complete("Success"); //this will work
       // changing "next" to "complete" makes it works     

    })
   return subjectTwoObserver;
  }
}
```

in my component I want to call both of these function simultaneously and wait for both of them to respond for that I used ForkJoin like this

```js
import { forkJoin, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {subjectServices} from './subjectServices.ts'
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private SubjectServices : subjectServices){
  }

  callBothSubjectSimultaneously(){
    let response1 = this.SubjectServices.observableOne();
    let response2 = this.SubjectServices.observableTwo();
    let allResponse = ForkJoin(response1, response2);
    allResponse.subscribe(responseList =>{
      let responseData1 = responseList[0];
      let responseData2= responseList[1];
      console.log("forkJoin completed")
    });
  }
}
```

though both the functions are executing the next() statement from the service but code inside allResponse.subscribe never gets triggered.

I know this would work if I feed the http call directly in the ForkJoin function but somehow it is not working if the observable is coming from a subject that I have declared.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to complete them: `complete()`. ForkJoin only emits after observables complete, not when they emit. Or use `combineLatest` instead.

Comment: ForkJoin only emits its value when all observable **complete**. If you are trying to return a subject for sake of using one value in multiple places there is a pipe operator that makes one observable shared for all subscribers

Comment: @ritaj thanks, it worked that way. updated the code as well